# MongoDB projection - take first element from Array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My field "Field1.Field2" is an array and I want to take only first element of this array, i.e. "Field1.Field2.0" and from this I want to take any other given field for example: "Field1.Field2.0.Field3". Unfortunately when I use this projection in  PyMongo then it doesn't work (this "0" make problems). The projection doesn't throw an error but the field "0" doesnt contain any values after projection while it contain the values before projection. What may be the reason?

Comment: you can not access it by index, you have to use operators, `$first` or `$arrayElemAt`

Comment: ```$slice``` also works =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:aggregation/$arrayAt or $first**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $addFields: {
     x: {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$x",
        0
       ]
     }
   }
 }
])
```

[Playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lU80x06vW1K)

**Option 2:aggregation/$slice**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $addFields: {
  x: {
    "$slice": [
      "$x",
      1
    ]
   }
  }
 }
])
```

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fcvl1yJuAN9)

**Option 3:find/project/$slice**

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  x: {
    $slice: 1
  }
})
```

[Playground 3](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qKxborGBDOe)